# Read a txt file in Eclipse/Java using blackbox class

Tags: java, eclipse, function

I'm a Uni student trying to multiply two matrices stored in txt files via java and Eclipse. We were given a pre-compiled class file, but not the source code for the class file, essentially making it a blackbox class. We're supposed to use vim and the Linux terminal to program and execute our java code, but I find that Ecplise is far more time-efficient. However, when using the Linux terminal and vim my program works as intended, whereas when using Eclipse it does not.

Here's my source code with only the LOCs using the blackbox class

```
String fileOne = ArrayReader.getFileName("Enter the file name of matrix one");
int[][] matrixOne = ArrayReader.readArray(fileOne);

String fileTwo = ArrayReader.getFileName("Enter the file name of matrix two");
int[][] matrixTwo = ArrayReader.readArray(fileTwo);
```

The getFileName function outputs the argument, expecting the user to enter the file name (including the extension) of the file with the elements of the matrix in it. If it doesn't find the file, it returns an error message stating so, then asking for the file name again. The readArray function simply gets the elements and assigns them to the elements of the integer matrix.

I've tried putting the txt files in both my src and bin folders in my project directory, and inputting the file names with and without the file extension multiple times, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried providing the full path to the file? like - 'D:/test.txt'

Comment: Also, why not use *Java decompiler* to check the code in the blackbox class, just to understand how the file is read?

Comment: @Prasann the lecturer/unit coordinator doesn't want us to check the source code (hence why it wasn't provided) for whatever reason, but I suppose I could give it a shot.

Comment: Well, how do you know if there is any issue with the code being supplied? Is that tested and proven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ArrayReader class expects the computer to be using Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I should put this in a comment but i don't have enough reputations

***Can you provide more details about the error so we can help and try to decompile the class to view it's source code you may find your answer also you can hardcode the file name (write it directly in the code) to test if everything works correctly ***